# Set SMTP mail server in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm new to Magento 2.1 and want to develop some marketplace. I want to send e-mails for order confirmation, new user emails etc.

How can I set up email for this?

Comment: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp refer this link.

Comment: I used this extension but i cant send emails. When test email,It will say time out

Comment: Take a screenshot in you config of this module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server does not have mail service installed, then you need to install custom SMTP extension.

You can take a look at some of these extensions and choose one as per your preference.

- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/
- https://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/custom-smtp-email-settings-for-magento2.html
- https://store.webkul.com/SMTP-Configurator-Magento2.html

I am using [Mageplaza SMTP extension](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/) and below are my settings for Gmail:

- **Enable Mageplaza SMTP:** Yes
- **Host:** smtp.gmail.com
- **Port:** 587
- **Authentication:** Login
- **Username:** [my-gmail-id]
- **Password:** [my-gmail-password]
- **Protocol:** TLS

Comment: I try these settings   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L2Me2UQiUQIK2VhQgDQooOE_hs3HlDwG but test email sending time out

Comment: I am using https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/ and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Please use settings mentioned above in my updated answer.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Can u please tell me which version you are the SMTP module as well as the magento version . SMTP is not working for me in magento 2.1.15

Comment: I checked for version 2.1.8 as well as 2.2.3+ versions. Also now Magento 2.2.x versions have Dot Mailer module prepackaged, so there is no need for any external module for SMTP.